# How do I assign a key based on count of available keys and indicator value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I need some help writing a formula that does the following:

1. Looks to see if an indicator=1
2. If indicator=1, lookup the key value based on the number available for that particular key
3. Keep looking up additional values, using the history of the used keys for that particular row
4. Reset and repeat for the next row

As an example:

```
COLUMN   A      B   C   D       E       F   G   H       I       J   K   L   M
         Row    Indicators      |       Matched Key     |       Key Counts          
           3    U1  U2  U3      |       U1  U2  U3      |       A   B   C   D
           4    1   0   1       |       B   N/A D       |       0   1   0   1   
           5    1   1   1       |       A   A   D       |       2   0   0   2
```

The formula I need to write is for the "Matched Key" section.

Reading row 4 from the left:

- U1 and U3 both have indicators, so I reach into the Key Counts table on find that I have 1 B and   one D
- U1 in "Matched Key" gets "B" as its key and U3 in "Matched Key" gets D.  U2 is assigned no value since its indicator is set to 0.

On row 5:

- U1, U2, and U3 all require key assignment.
- I look in "Key Counts" and see that I have 2 A's and 1 D.
- U1 and U2 get the A's and U3 gets one of the Ds (there will be one leftover).

Comment: Why does U2 get assigned A in row 5?

Comment: I have 2 "A" key counts available in row 5, the priority of assigning keys works from left to right.  So first I will use all available A's, then B's, etc.

Comment: @mrkb80 Please edit your formula into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question using array formulas (this formula is for cell H4):

```
{=IF(D4=1,OFFSET($I$2,0,COLUMN(INDEX(OFFSET($J$4,0, ( (MIN(IF((J4:M4>=1) *(J4:M4<>0)*(O4:R4>=SUM(B4:D4)),COLUMN(J4:M4)))-1))-COLUMN($I$2) ):$N$4,MATCH(TRUE,OFFSET($J$4,0,  ( (MIN(IF((J4:M4>=1) *(J4:M4<>0)*(O4:R4>=SUM(B4:D4)),COLUMN(J4:M4)))-1))-COLUMN($I$2)  ):$N$4>=1,0)))-COLUMN($I$4)),NA())}
```

I had to add one more "matrix" which is for cumulative counts (which is in the O4:R5 range):

```
COLUMN  N     O    P   Q    R
        Row   Cumulative Counts         
          3    A    B   C   D
          4    1    2   4   4
          5    2    2   2   3
```

Other ways to skin this cat, but this works for me.